# Jquery .sortable is not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work out why my  jquery .sortable will not trigger.

```js
$(".table").sortable({
```

Here is the code it is meant to record which table the item is in and then save that to a MySQL database  so when the user loads the page again it will remain in those tables.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone"
  });

  $(".table").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable.clone();
      $(this).append(draggable);
      draggable.draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        helper: "clone"
      });
      ui.draggable.remove();

      //var targetTableId = $(this).attr('id');
      //alert("Item dropped into Table: " + targetTableId);
    }
  });

  $(".table").sortable({
    items: ".draggable",
    connectWith: ".table",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("Sortable initialized for table:", $(this).attr('id'));
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("UPDATE CALLED");
      var tableId = $(this).attr('id');
      var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
      saveChanges(tableId, order);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var tableId = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log("Table ID:", tableId);
    }
  });

  function saveChanges(tableId, order) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "save_changes.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        table_id: tableId,
        order: order
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.table {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.draggable {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Drag and Drop System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="table" id="table1">
      <h2>Table 1</h2>
      <div class="draggable" id="item1">Item 1</div>
      <div class="draggable" id="item2">Item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table" id="table2">
      <h2>Table 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

And the save changes php file.

```php
<?php
// Connection to your database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "your_database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$table_id = $_POST['table_id'];
$order = $_POST['order'];

// Update the database with the new order
$sql = "UPDATE your_table SET order_column = '$order' WHERE table_id = '$table_id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Changes saved successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

`$conn->close();`
`?>`
```

I've tried to find where it is not triggering and swapped between different classes and IDs in the html cross checked the Jquery to make sure it matches and it is loading in the correct order but I just can't get it to trigger $(".table").sortable({ or log anything to the console.

Comment: Please have a look at how to create a [mre]. Half of the code you've posted doesn't concern the problem you are experiencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your code, I'm not sure you even need the `draggable`, and  `droppable` code at all. Indeed it is this conflicting with the `sortable` code that is confusing the issue.

So, you can simplify it to just `sortable`as that already does what you need. This way you can drag and drop the items between `tables` and have your `saveChanges` pass the change to be saved on the back-end e.g.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table").sortable({
    items: ".draggable",
    connectWith: ".table",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("Sortable initialized for table:", $(this).attr('id'));
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("UPDATE CALLED");
      var tableId = $(this).attr('id');
      var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
      saveChanges(tableId, order);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var tableId = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log("Table ID:", tableId);
    }
  });

  function saveChanges(tableId, order) {
    console.log('saveChanges', tableId, order);
    $.ajax({
      url: "save_changes.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        table_id: tableId,
        order: order
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.table {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.draggable {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Drag and Drop System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table" id="table1">
      <h2>Table 1</h2>
      <div class="draggable" id="item1">Item 1</div>
      <div class="draggable" id="item2">Item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table" id="table2">
      <h2>Table 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Fraser, I see I didn't know that the drag/droppable stopped the  sortable. Thank you for making that clear learnt something new :), I've accepted the answer and would say it is useful but as I'm new it won't let me sorry. I appreciate your help and quick response thank you.

Comment: @user23448609 No worries at all, welcome to Stackoverflow! Issues like this can be tricky to spot because there aren't any errors per se, rather it is just not working as you expected. FWIW I thought your question was fine, you explained the problem and gave the relevant code. Your attempt to log in the console was also a really good way to debug the issue - as it demonstrated clearly which code was being executed and which wasn't :)